# Semaphore Problems, not Waiting

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, semaphore

I have one problem with semaphores, I though you could help me..
Okay first off let me show what I am doing.
I have to c programs, one server and other named client.

On server I do this:

```
#ifdef _SEM_SEMUN_UNDEFINED    //here I define semun, in case that is not defined
#undef _SEM_SEMUN_UNDEFINED
union semun {
int val;
struct semid_ds *buf;
unsigned short int *array;
struct seminfo *__buf;
};
#endif

union semun semopts;
int semID;

semID = semget(1000, 1, 0600 | IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL); //I want this gives error, if there is already a sem on that key
if(semID < 0){
   perror(semID);
   exit(1);
}
semopts.val = 10;
semctl(semID, 0, SETVAL, semopts);  //Here I set the val for the first sem of the group, I want it with value 10
```

Okay this is my server file, now on client, what I need to do is:

10 clients can read from memory at same time, so for each reader I do -1 on the sem.
1 client can write on memory at same time and no one can read, so in this case, I do -10 on the sem, right??

So here is my client program:

```
struct sembuf UP10 = {0, 10, 0};
struct sembuf DOWN10 = {0, -10, 0};
struct sembuf UP1 = {0, 1, 0};
struct sembuf DOWN1 = {0, -1, 0};
int semID;
semID = semget(1000, 1, 0600 | IPC_CREAT);
if(semID < 0){
  perror(semID);
  exit(1);
}

//Okay now its here on my switch where they read or write

switch(selection[0]){ //This store the number from a scanf
case '1':

semop(semID, &DOWN1, 1);
functionToRead(..);
semop(semID, &UP1, 1);
break;

case '2': //Here the client also read from memory

semop(semID, &DOWN1, 1);
functionToReadAlsoMemory(...);
semop(semID, &UP1, 1);
break;

case '3': //Here is the block where the client WRITES on memory so use the struct DOWN10 and UP10

semop(semID, &DOWN10, 1);
functionToWriteOnMemory(...);
semop(semID, &UP10, 1);
break;

}
```

Okay so the problem is :

when I press 3 (block to write on memory), program does -10 on sem, and enter on that function, there are scanf, so the sem will have 0 till it exits from the function.. when user presses enter and goes through the scanf.
In this case, if on client is writing and I try to open another client and write, it keeps waiting till the other client leaves the function and does the sem UP10. OKAY its good, thats what I want, and then the client that was waiting goes through that function to write.. OKAY GOOD

But if one client is on that function (that client did DOWN10, so sem 0), and I try to read from memory (on case '1' or case '2'), he ACTUALY can! But should not!! 
Because if sem is still on 0, he cannot make sem DOWN1, right??

I guess you guys understood my problem here, I have the includers for sem and such, the problem is not there, right? because it works for 2 clients trying to write..

Would be really nice if you guys figured out where is my problem :s
Thanks alot in advance, cheers!!

Comment: You need to check return values from functions like `semop`. Otherwise, you'll never figure out what goes wrong.

Comment: what do you mean? what semop returns ? 0 or -1 ? in case of sucess or error ? thanks for you reply mate!

Comment: For example, if `semop` is *failing* it's obviously not going to be wait for the semaphore to change.

Comment: I guess that 'selection' is passed in as a parameter to the function containing the switch?

Comment: yes it is Martin James, why?
Thanks for you reply guys

Comment: selection being passed as argument makes any problem with my semaphores ?

Comment: @DarkLink - OK, what was it, I want to know!

Comment: @DarkLink - OK, I got it from your comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semaphores are a difficult tool that are much too low-level for normal userspace code. Consider using POSIX' control structures `pthread_mutex_t` and `pthread_cond_t`, instead. They can easily be used in shared memory between processes, nowadays.

One of the main problems with semaphores is that the calls can be interrupted by any kind of signal, in particular if IO is delivered to your process. You'd have to capture the return value and error codes that the calls provide, and then go into waiting again.

Comment: POSIX semaphores are a bit nicer than the old SysV ones. I actually like them better than mutexes and cond variables for many common one-off type signalling tasks because you don't need a predicate; the semaphore value is the predicate waited on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jens, but I need to do this with semaphores :s
and with this exercise its possible, told my teacher, but I cant find the mistake here :s
Thanks guys

Comment: @R.., I like futexes best, but that's not the question here :) semaphores are really difficult for beginners because of their interuptability. POSIX conditions are much simpler to get right when you start with these things.

Comment: `while(sem_wait(&sem));` is not much harder to write than `sem_wait(&sem);` :-)

Comment: @DarkLink, ah you forgot the homework tag :) without kidding, then do as I said: **always** capture the return value of these functions, inspect `errno` and decide how to proceed. And perhaps glance into the manual page for the semaphore functions? They have some nice information, there.

Comment: Problem solved I had a minor mistake on my struct x)
here was fine, but on my code, was like:
struct sembuf DOWN1 = {1, -1, 0};
LOOL xD

Comment: @R..  hmm if a 'semaphore' wait can be interrupted and passed without a signal operation on the 'semaphore', it's not a semaphore.  Perhaps they should call it something else, 'SemaphoreUnlessSignalReceived', 'SemaphoreMostOfTheTime', 'NearlyASemaphore'?  Anyway, I don't think that this issue causes the OP's problem - seems to me like it should work OK.

Comment: @Martin: No, it's just that the wait operation can fail. There's also a timed wait operation that can fail due to timeout. This doesn't make it any less of a semaphore... You can always restart the wait if you want, or you can handle the exceptional condition instead of doing what you were waiting to do.